# What is the best way to position span element under 2 flexbox row elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

Here is my **HTML** -

```
<div className={classes['container']}>
    <div className={classes['svgContainer']}>
        <AuthSvg />
    </div>
    <div className={classes['formContainer']}>
        <form className={classes['form']} onSubmit={props.submitHandler}>
            <h1 className={classes['form__header']}>Join our website</h1>
            <Input />
            <div className="btnwrapper">
                <button className={classes['form__button']} type='submit'>
                    Register
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <span className={classes['text']}>Already have an account? <a>Click Here</a></span>
</div>
```

Compiled **CSS** -

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  direction: rtl;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  user-select: none;
}

button:enabled {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

mark {
  padding: 4px;
}

menu {
  padding: 0;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

So, there is the 'container' class which is flexbox: row.
And inside the class there is the 'svgContainer' class and 'formContainer'.
I want to add the 'text' class below the 'formContainer' class, what is the best way to do that?
.....................................................................................................

Comment: Can you share compiled css?

Comment: @SatoTakeru added, and here is the github if you like, thx!
https://github.com/daniel-bar/movies-app

Comment: is there a specific reason you want to use <span>(inline) rather than using a <p>tag which is a block element and would give you the layout that you need without using flex?

Comment: @nontechguy no, i can use p tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if I understand correctly you have the following layout.
[image]

and you would like this

[image]

There are many ways to achieve what you want. Wrapping the .svgContainer and .formContainers in a div with display flex will give you flex-direction row. Then the .innerContainer and .spanContainer will behave like normal block level elements and stack.

HTML

```
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <div class="svgContainer">.svgContainer</div>
        <div class="formContainer">.formContainer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="spanContainer"><span>span</span><div>
</div>
```

css

```
.outerContainer{
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
}
.innerContainer{
  display:flex;
  background-color:#04B2D9;
  padding:10px;
}
.svgContainer{
  color:#BF5B04;
  background-color:#F28705;
  border:1px solid #592202;
  padding:10px;
}
.formContainer{
  color:#F28705;
  background-color:#BF5B04;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #592202;
}
.spanContainer{
  padding:10px;
}
span{
  color:#F2B84B;
  background-color:#592202;
  padding:10px;
}
```

codepen here
https://codepen.io/non_tech_guy/pen/xxLxLdE